# ubuntu server does not function in gui mode

Tags: server

Prior to downloading the server- ubuntu desktop. I verified connectivity. I see a CD/ROM on the E: drive. this is new. I go by the recommended procedure of VHD in SCSI and don't know where to go to CD/ROM, scsi, ide, nvme? really it is like rocket science.
I installed server before and it was a beauty with GUI. I had to change my SSD to bigger one on the computer. I installed windows server, debian package, REHL, and even ubuntu desktop. But server does not give me connection to the network. It is just a morroon shell that is dead.

Comment: yes, gui on server. The Ubuntu Gui desktop is what I want. release is 18.04.2. I go to -sudo apt install tasksel, then click on ubuntu desktop, ok, then sudo reboot. once there, I see a blank shell moroon color, just like the desktop. no lights, nothing. just dead

Comment: i already installed kali and the ubuntu desktop and had no problems, installed vmware tools that makes it just like my windows 10 experience. But the server installation is fine all the way to the point where it leads off to the GUI. Then goes dead. I had connectivity and could do everything pretty much in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop gnome-shell
```

Package name has changed since 17.10 and by the way a server has no gui.